# Upgraded from 3.1.2 to 3.2.1.Release, can't resolve @repository and getJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I just updated my pom.xml references to get the latest version of spring, and now I am getting errors for **@Transaction and @Repository** references in my code.

I added spring-tx which seams to have fixed my @transaction references, but where is @repository now?

Other errors that I can't figure out are:

**getJdbcTemplate doesnt' seem to resolve.
RowMapper also doesn't resolve.**

Where did these move to?

Why did this change happen?  It would be nice if all annotations where in a single maven repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find both jdbc method and row mapper class under the spring-jdbc jar and you should add spring-context jar for @Repository annotation.

Answer (score 1):

For @Repository please add following in pom.xml:-

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

`org.springframework.stereotype.Repository` is in `spring-context` (has been since 2.0). `getJdbcTemplate` is obviously a method. In which class do you expect it?

Comment: looks like it moved to jdbc, i had to add a new entry in my pom.